# CBLQuery map/reduce for arrays property

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-view

I have an existing json structure like this stored in one document. How can I use CBLQuery map/reduce for the events array?

```
{
        "_id": "subject:6688",
        "_rev": "29-d3aad012fc362578e8a9b652918f419d",
        "subjectId": 6688,
        "title",
        "events": [
            {
                "eventId",
                "subjectId",
                "createdDateStr",
                "createdDateEpoch"
            }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the ensuing discussion on the Couchbase Lite mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/mobile-couchbase/jza9wxFvFO4/HGXfzaoGlgwJ

The Couchbase Lite documentation on views is here:
http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/view/index.html